# Как проверить, что очередь в Laravel отработала?

Tags: laravel, laravel5, redis

Я использую Laravel 5.4 вместе с Redis. Я хочу проверить закончила ли моя очередь async_jobs свою работу, чтобы мониторить активные и завершенные очереди. Redis подключил нормально, в конфигах всё ок, сам использую get и set вместе с ним. Нашел команду LLEN, но она возвращает каждый раз ноль, в то время как очередь запущена. Как мне решить эту проблему? И возможно ли остановить работу очередь?

```
    AsyncCheckerJob::dispatch($el,$cnt,$num_jobs)->onQueue('async_jobs'.'_'.$id);
    $redis = app('redis');
    $queueSize = $redis->llen('queues:' . 'async_jobs'.'_'.$id);
```